# Error: Cannot find module 'E:\my-project\android\undefined'

Tags: android, react-native

After the downgrade, the react-native version and I got this error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\GPS-react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 195
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'E:\my-project\android\undefined'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

[Here is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5JxT.png)

Here is my downgraded package.json file.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build": "expo build:android",
    "build:ios": "expo build:ios",
    "fingerprint": "expo fetch:android:hashes",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chartiful/react-native-chart-builder": "^0.1.8",
    "@chartiful/react-native-vertical-bar-graph": "^0.1.2",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^1.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "expo": "^40.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-updates": "~0.4.0",
    "firebase": "7.9.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",                                     --------------> only here is different
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",                              --------------> only here is different
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.11.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-display-keyboard": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.6.1",
    "react-native-normalize": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-steps": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-timeago": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.12.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-viro": "^2.17.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-range-slider": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",         --------------> only here is different
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.10",      --------------> only here is different
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",           --------------> only here is different
    "jest": "^26.6.3",                 --------------> only here is different
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.65.2",          --------------> only here is different
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"                        --------------> only here is different
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "guix",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

and here is the package.json before downgrade.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build": "expo build:android",
    "build:ios": "expo build:ios",
    "fingerprint": "expo fetch:android:hashes",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chartiful/react-native-chart-builder": "^0.1.8",
    "@chartiful/react-native-vertical-bar-graph": "^0.1.2",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^1.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "expo": "^40.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-updates": "~0.4.0",
    "firebase": "7.9.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.11.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-display-keyboard": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.6.1",
    "react-native-normalize": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-steps": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-timeago": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.12.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-viro": "^2.17.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-range-slider": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.12.10",
    "babel-jest": "~26.6.3",
    "babel-preset-expo": "8.3.0",
    "jest": "~26.6.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "~17.0.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "guix",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Why I get this error? How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: Do you use react-viro?